# java.net.UnknownHostException: when trying to connect to heroku postgres through intellij

Tags: postgresql, heroku, intellij-idea

I have just signed up to a free heroku account hoping to try and see if a web app I am making functions properly, all works fine on my local machine connected locally to my postgres db.

I am trying to connect to the heroku postgres db I set up. I have connected fine through pgadmin and also in the application.yaml file so that when in prod profile, it runs on the heroku postgres database.

But if I try and connect to the DB using the intellij database connection, I keep getting an error,

`[08001] The connection attempt failed. java.net.UnknownHostException: ec2-54-73-110-26.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I have checked everything several times, and all the fields on the database connection wizard are correct. I have also set ssl to true, sslmode to verify-ca and sslfactory to sslfactory:org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

but I get the above error each time.

Comment: do you have any VPN or SSH tunnels running while connecting to database? what is in your 'hosts' file?  just checked this address from my side in Idea - it says 'wrong password' which is expected. so the problem is somewhere in routing on your side I guess.

Comment: I am not running any VPN or SSH tunnels. I do get the password incorrect error if I dont change any of the settings in the advanced tab